# SMOTE-NC in R. No packages found

Tags: r, oversampling, imbalanced-data, smote

I have a dataset with 5 nominal and 37 categorical variables. I want to perform oversampling in R. However, with SMOTE, I cannot do so. I looked for SMOTE-NC as advised by (Chawla, Bowyer and Hall, 2002), but I could not find any package supporting it. How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
to see what and  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be any R implementation for SMOTE-NC. Either you write your own or you use e.g. the Python library instead.

Answer (score 0):

SMOTENC is only developed for Python (as of today). What it does is unlike SMOTE, SMOTE-NC can be used for datasets containing numerical and categorical features. However, it is not designed to work with only categorical features.

In your case for R, `ROSE` and `SMOTE` are designed to handle categorical variables, so, unless your categorical variables are expressed in a binary format, you should not worry about them being a categorical variable. However, if they are not expressed in a binary format, you will need to convert all those categorical variables to a binary format. Here is an example if you would be trying to convert a categorical variable called `class` to a binary format:

```
df$class <- as.factor(df$class)
levels(df$class) <- c(1,0)
```

This converts the variable `class` to 0 and 1. Once you do this for all categorical variavbles, you should be able to use `SMOTE` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `RSBID` package in *R* has `SMOT_NC()`.

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("dongyuanwu/RSBID")

newdata <- SMOTE_NC(data, outcome, perc_maj = 100, k = 5)
```

https://rdrr.io/github/dongyuanwu/RSBID/man/SMOTE_NC.html